# NameError in python, Program was working fine moments ago

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a small windows application using python. My code was running a few moments ago. Now it is showing some errors. I am very consfused how this has happened. Moments ago code was working fine. now errors has appeared. My CODE :-

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

class MyApp(Frame):
def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    self.master.title("Music Library")
    self.parent=parent
    self.images = []
    self.createUI()


def createUI(self):
    self.grid()
    raw_data=Image.open("pic.jpg")
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(raw_data)
    label=tk.Label(image = image)
    self.images.append(image)
    label.grid(column=0,row=0)
    btn = tk.Button(text="Click Me")
    btn.grid(column=0,row=0)


root=tk.Tk()
app=MyApp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

The Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "D:\DeepakK\Python programs\Background Image.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks Every one. I have resolved the issue. The issue might be because of some Namespace resolution error. The same can be correcte by adding : from tkinter import *

Comment: _adding_ `from tkinter import *` is not a proper fix, because you have two different ways of importing tkinter. That will result in very confusing code.

Comment: May I know why you have degrade my question? I am very new to python, so if there is any mistake in the code that instead of degarding please help me to let know.

Comment: Your question shows absolutely no sign that you did any research to try and solve this before asking the question. This is not a question that is likely to be useful for anyone else.

Comment: Ohhk. But as I said I am new to python and my code was working some time ago and suddenly stopped working. Anyways Thanks for the Info

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a "get out of jail free" card --  you're expected to do some research before asking a question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.master.title("Music Library")
        self.parent=parent
        self.images = []
        self.createUI()
```

You should prefix `Frame` with `tk` (just like above) or use `from tkinter import *` and then call `Frame` like you did.